# iOS: xctest (48745) encountered an error (Failed to create a bundle instance representing, Check that the bundle exists on disk

Tags: ios, jenkins-pipeline, bundle, xctestcase

I am getting error in my Jenkin pipeline. Test case running locally but it failed in jenkin pipeline with following error:

xctest (48745) encountered an error (Failed to create a bundle instance representing '/Users/vagrant/workspace/ex-libs_insurance-ios-lib_PR-620/build/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectNameTests.xctest'.
Check that the bundle exists on disk.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema that you test. Maybe your test target of your pod ins't included there.

I had the same issue. After adding target in scheme, the error gone.
I hope it helps!